# Excel COUNTIFS formula match 'not' x

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

So, I have two columns of interest, which I want to be able to `COUNTIFS` on, an example of the sort of data is as follows.

```
Stage | Revasc
I     |   N
II    |   N
I     |   CABG
III   |   PCI
AE    |   CABG+PCI
```

I wanted to count these as two variables, one of numbers with revasc, and numbers without, but the easiest way I can think of this would be:

```
COUNTIFS(A2:A6, "I", B2:B6, "NOT N")
```

But I can't find how to represent `NOT` in excel formulae. In usual regex it would be `!N` but this clearly doesn't work. Any pointers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `=COUNTIFS(A2:A6, "I", B2:B6, "<>N")`